# Why are these Forest Retreats Dwarven, and not Elven?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I am new to Dwarf Fortress, so I do not know that much about World Generation.

Why does my map have *DWARVEN* Forest Retreats? I have looked on the map. Their is one Dwarven Necromancer on the same continent. So maybe they took it over.
[image: Dwarven Forest Retreat]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was conquered from the elves by a dwarven civilization at some point.